# Can you set up GCM on windows server?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to use [GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html#server-setup) and was wondering if it was possible to set it up on Windows Server (IIS) instead?

Currently my web services are all hosted on Windows Servers as WCF services. I'd like to avoid having to have a dedicated server for GCM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of what? Any server connected to the internet can be used as a sender of GCM messages. Your Android application has to be able to connect your server in order to pass the device Registration ID to it. And your server has to be able to send POST requests to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` in order to send the messages.

Or as stated in the [GCM Documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) :

> Before you can write client Android applications that use the GCM
>   feature, you must have an application server that meets the following
>   criteria:
>
> 1. Able to communicate with your client.
> 2. Able to fire off HTTPS requests to the GCM server.
> 3. Able to handle requests and resend them as needed, using exponential back-off.
> 4. Able to store the API key and client registration IDs. The API key is included in the header of POST requests that send messages.

Comment: Instead of using a linux server with Jetty or tomcat. I'm wondering if the documentation left out that it must be a Java-capable server. Because the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app) on setting up the server call for using the `gcm-server/dist/gcm-server.jar` file.

Comment: That's just a helper library that eases the coding of the sender server, but you don't have to use it. You can make direct HTTP POST requests instead of using it. You can inspect the code of that library. There's nothing complicated about it.